# Get a certain query result from two different mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having the following problem:

I try to implement an achievementsystem. I have two tables. Table 1 contains the achievement_id and achievement_info. Table 2 contains the link to the user, meaning achievement_id and player_id, so that you can tell which user has achieved certain things.

I'm trying to write a method that returns me all achievements, but additionally a flag that tells me if a certain user has achieved this row or not.
E.g.: getPlayerAchievements(playerid) --> returns a list of Achievements with id, info, and a bool flag whether the user has achieved it.

table 1:

```
achievement_id|achievement_info  
1             |info1  
2             |info2  
3             |info3
```

table 2:

```
achievement_id|player_id;  
1             |15  
3             |15
```

the result I need by entering the player_id "15":

```
achievement_id|achievement_info|(bool)achieved  
1             |info1           |true  
2             |info2           |false  
3             |info3           |true
```

I already have the achievement class so I just have to fill them with my data.

I could always use two seperate sql queries to achieve that, but I thought maybe there was a way to simplify it, since I use php to get my data and don't want two connections and queries in one php script.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select all records from the achievemets table and show them. That's the easy part :-) For every record you want to show whether player 1234 has attained this achievement. You can do this with an `EXISTS` clause:

```
select 
  achievement_id, 
  achievement_info,
  exists 
  (
    select * 
    from players p 
    where p.player_id = 1234 
      and p.achievement_id = a.achievement_id
  ) as achieved
from achievements a;
```

Or even simpler with `IN`:

```
select 
  achievement_id, 
  achievement_info,
  achievement_id in (select achievement_id from players where player_id = 1234) as achieved
from achievements;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! that did the job!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` to get a complete list of achievements and the matching records from the user's achievements table:

```
select t1.achievement_id, t1.achievement_info, (t2.achievement_id is null) as achieved
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.achievement_id=t2.achievement_id and t2.player_id=15
```

Comment: ... provided there are no multiple achievements per user in the table (i.e. provided achievement_id + player_id are unique in the achievements table). Otherwise you might have to get rid of duplicates.